# USB port change suddenly

Tags: 20.04, usb

I have a device that is connect to computer with USB1 port. Sometimes USB1 port suddenly changes to USB3 port. After i restart my computer it goes back to USB1 port again. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Show the `dmesg` output, log file contents or output / error messages related to the problem.

Comment: Firmware settings (ie. box specific values) can influence the order in which ports are read..  which is why UUIDs are preferred over port name/numbers.  Your question though is about hardware, and you've not yet mentioned how this relates to software or your Ubuntu 20.04 Server/Desktop install & this site.

Comment: Check you applications which use this port. Sometimes application hangs device and system reinitializes it with another name. Study `dmesg` output as @Bodo recommended in comment.